# How do I import all global variables into a function - Python

Tags: python, variables, global-variables

I am attempting to import all global variables into multiple functions, it would be great if I could just call on a function such as this:

```
def importGlobals():
    global name, version, edition, fullName, method, printSize, printed, oldPrint, print
```

like so

```
def myFunction():
    importGlobals()
    print(name) # name is a global variable
```

Is there any way to do this other than copying the insides of `importGlobals` to EVERY function I need to use them all? The above solution does not work... Neither does this one:

```
def importGlobals():
    global name, version, edition, fullName, method, printSize, printed, oldPrint, print

def myFunction():
    print(name)

importGlobals()
myFunction()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Import from where? You do know that _gloal_ variables are accessible from everywhere without the `global` keyword right? It is only when you try to update the variables you need to use `global`.

Comment: What are the global variables intended for? Using global variables is bad practice. I’ve found that creating variables in a separate py file and importing that py file in to the file you plan on using it to. As an example put variables in a py file named global_variables create your variables there and import the module into the file you’re using them in and access them like global_variables.name ; I use this for when I deal with classes

Comment: is there a reason you're not just typing 'global x, y, z' at the top of the script? If you do that, then all the local function environments have it. right now you are calling a function to push variables from local to global which doesn't make sense?

Comment: @AnnaNevison there is a reason which he stated. He has alot of functions and want to avoid on doing that in all of them

Comment: @Tomerikoo so multiple scripts?

Comment: because if he had multiple functions on the same script, he could just define them in the global environment (i.e. outside the function) so all the local function environments had access to them.

Comment: not to modify... also doing `global` at the top of a script has no effect or sense whatsoever. variables defined at top module level are *global* by default

Comment: Also, thanks @`JohanL`, that's a helpful thing to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in the comment, another way of accessing variables is to implement them in a separate py file and import them in the file you want to access them in as follows;

Main.py

```
import global_variables

def myFunction():
    print(global_variables.name)
    global_variables.name = "David"
    print(global_variables.name)

def myOtherFunction():
    print(global_variables.name)
    global_variables.name = "Aaron"
    print(global_variables.name)

myFunction()
myOtherFunction()
```

global_variables.py

```
# you can use any type for your variables and still access them in another module

name = "John"
version = {"Version":1.0} # access version by global_variables.version["Version"]
edition = ["Edition1"]  # access edition by global_variables.edition[0]
fullName = "John Smith"
value = 5.33
```

Output:

```
John
David
David
Aaron
```

Comment: I can modify the variables as I please from `global_variables.py` inside `main.py` correct?

Comment: Yes you can. You can just assign it a value like any other variable.

Comment: @Techtiger255CodeMode As a side note, you can access the variables by a shorter name if you change ```import global_variables``` to ```import global_variables as gv``` and access the variables like ```gv.name```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good idea. It is hard because it should be hard. If you want several functions to have access to shared state, you should use a class.

```py
class GlobalState:
    # avoid overloading print
    def __init__(name, version, edition, fullName, method, printSize, printed, oldPrint, _print):
        self.name = name
        self.version = version
        ...

    def myFunction(self):
        print(self.name)
        print(self.version)
```

This is the idiomatic way of doing what you want.

Comment: I only overload print because I am changing the default values for the end parameter actual use: `from functools import partial`<\n>`print = partial(oldPrint, end=method, sep='')` and `oldPrint` retains the exact same code...

Comment: I could do this, however, I think that @`Drees` method is a bit cleaner, but I'll use this if I ever have to use 1 file only (like a code challenge or something idk)...

Comment: I get why you're overloading print, it's just less good than naming it anything else. It doesn't cause any technical issues but it harms the readability of your code.

Comment: I guess... but we all have our own styles... and It really is basically the same function... But point taken... thanks. :thumbs_up: